# Is it possible to write a cordova plugin using the Cast v3 SDK on android?

Tags: cordova, google-cast

I need to write a cast sender app on Android and iOS using Cordova. The iOS v3 Cast SDK allows the developer to get a list of discovered cast devices by using the GCKDiscoveryManager and to connect to them using the GCKSessionManager.
I can't find the same functions on Android, it seems that most of the logic is automatically managed by the cast button widget which cannot be used in a Cordova app. Should I switch back to the v2 SDK thus losing the reconnection service and other nice features provided by the v3 framework? Am I missing something?

Comment: have you ever get this to work? Have you found a working cordova plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

For Android the Cast dialogs are part of the Media Router and managed by them internally. If you want to support other devices with their own discovery protocols, then you can implement a Media Router provider using the standard Android APIs.